# Are salesforce reports persistent objects on the database?

Tags: reporting, bulk-api

Are salesforce.com reports actual objects that can be accessed on the database (e.g. using the BULK API)?

Or are they really only metadata containing the queries required to return the data 'on the fly' when a user runs a report?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that Report object in salesforce store information about the report like name , developername, Description. however reports object and columns are stored in metadata . We can't use the BuLK API to get the data from reports. However,  you can query the data using the bulk API.

Comment: Also of relevance, report object fields are read-only.

Comment: @amidstCloud Thanks so much for the response! I am new to using the SFDC API, so just to clarify the above: When you say query the data using the bulk API, you are referring to the underlying objects (e.g. Accounts, Cases, etc.) right, not being able to query the reports' data directly using the API?

Comment: Yes. You are the object data not the report data